Customise "Add a New Post" page
I have a very simple question to which I am sure there is a simple answer, but after hours of searching I still can't find it.
I am a professional programmer who has been developing themes and plugins for WordPress since it came on the scene.
For a current client I developed a new tailored theme, which of course includes its own single.php template. But the individual who is responsible for adding new posts simply tries to copy great chunks of text and photos from local news outlets. Many of these are themselves WordPress sites. He has absolutely no understanding of HTML and cannot handle any of the the TinyMCE options provided by the Classic Editor.
I need a way of customising the "Add a New Post" page so that he has to (in effect) fill in a form. He can add a new paragraph, but then will be obliged to copy only text into it. He can add headings in the same way. He can add media, but only if he has first copied the single media item to the Media Library.
Is there an exiting plugin which will allow me to substitute something like this for both the Classic Editor and the Block Editor?

have tried to make a new custom post type for that ?

Thank you for the suggestion. I have, of course, but the new type would be so generic that I am sure someone else has already coded it! I don't want to bill my client for development time when I could use someone else's working code (acknowledging the coder, of course)

If the only objective is to differentiate between headings and text, I think block editor should work. One can easily grasp the concept of different blocks for different content. It's quite intuitive in that aspect.

Thank you. Unfortunately, my client, who is 85 and fiercely "untechnical" is not up to understanding the block editor.
